# multiple pthreads are called multiple times; slower than serial code

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am solving 4 eqns on a 2D discrete domain (LX,LY). These 4 eqns needs to solved for 1000's of time steps.
each eqn will need parameter a, b and c at (i,j) location.
I dynamically created a_m, b_m, and c_m in main() and I will pass their address to each thread.

I created 4 functions eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4.

I am creating LX*LY number of threads for each eqn.
Each thread id will represnt an unique (i,j) in domain LX,LY.
Therefore, each thread will work at only a specific data location (i,j) in vectors a_m, b_m, c_m.
Then, I am calling 4 eqn's sequentially in main().
The 4 equations are supposed to be solved in sequence bcoz the parameters a, b and c are updated at each (i,j) by each equation.

My programme is running even slower than serial computing. Could you please suggest some optimization tricks for speed up.

I suppose creating 4 threads, one for each equation, and solving each thread for LX*LY times will not provide much speed up.

```
# define N LX*LY
struct thread_data
{
   int  thread_id, t;
   double *a, *b, *c ;
};

struct thread_data thread_data_array[N];


//Function declaration

void *eqn1(void *threadarg)
{
//implementation of eqn1
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}

void *eqn2(void *threadarg)
{
//implementation of eqn2

   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}

void *eqn3(void *threadarg)
{
//implementation of eqn3
   pthread_barrier_wait (&barrier);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}

void *eqn4(void *threadarg)
{
//implementation of eqn4
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

//main

```
void * main(void *)
{
  pthread_t threadid[N];
//dynamically create a_m, b_m and c_m of size N each
  for(time=0; time<10000; time++)
    {

      for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
        //thread_data_array[i] is initialized
        // *a,*b,*c in thread_data_array[i] will save address of a_m,b_m,c_m created dynamically in main()
        pthread_create(threadid[i], eq1, (void *) &thread_data_array[i] );
        }

      for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
        //thread_data_array[i] is initialized
        // *a,*b,*c in thread_data_array[i] will save address of a_m,b_m,c_m created dynamically in main()
        pthread_create(threadid[i], eq2, (void *) &thread_data_array[i] );
        }

      for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
        //thread_data_array[i] is initialized
        // *a,*b,*c in thread_data_array[i] will save address of a_m,b_m,c_m created dynamically in main()
        pthread_create(threadid[i], eq3, (void *) &thread_data_array[i] );
        }

      for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
        //thread_data_array[i] is initialized
        // *a,*b,*c in thread_data_array[i] will save address of a_m,b_m,c_m created dynamically in main()
        pthread_create(threadid[i], eq4, (void *) &thread_data_array[i] );
        }

        for(j=0;j<N; j++) {
        pthread_join( threadid[j], NULL);
       }

    }

free(a_m); free(b_m); free(c_m);

}
```

Comment: You know each of those successive for-loops destroys any chance of waiting on the just-launched, now-orphaned, threads from the prior loop, right? I.e. only the last set is waited on, and its no-doubt in direct contention with all those orphaned threads. And the first parameter to `pthread_create` is wrong anyway, it should be `threadid+i`, not `threadid[i]`, and your compiler should have told you that. As-written if this didn't fault I'd be amazed.

Comment: above is a pseudo-code and syntactically not accurate. you're right it should be &threadid[i].

Comment: It's not a good idea to post code that does not represent what you are actually doing. We can't read your mind. All we can read is the code and words that you have posted.

Comment: pseudo code has everything except the actual equation and syntactically correct variable declarations. I can assure you that original code is syntactically correct bcoz it has been compiled on VS2010 and Linux(gnu) and it does produce expected correct results. However, the speed is very slow.

Comment: there is a barrier in the equation 3 which I have now included in the pseudo code. I am not using mutex or any other special function in multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code has some errors. Your eq2, eq3, eq4 loops will orphan the threads created before. I think your code has undefined behavior. If you fix the code, then you could proceed to optimization.

One big problem is the thread creation overhead. You basically create and destroy the threads 1000 times. If the code associated with eq1, eq2 ... is simple, then the overhead generated by thread creation / destruction is high.

If you are not forced for using pthreads, I would go for OpenMP.

If you want to use pthreads, you probably need to implement a "thread pool"

If you go for OpenMP you will do something like this:

```
  for(time=0; time<10000; time++)
  {
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(i=0; i<N; i++)
      {
        eq1(&thread_data_array[i]);
        eq2(&thread_data_array[i]);
        eq3(&thread_data_array[i]);
        eq4(&thread_data_array[i]);
      }
   }
```

and the OpenMP runtime will know how many threads to launch depending on your machine.

Comment: I am doing this exercise with pthread to make a speed comparison between MPI and multi-threading. I can't mix MPI with multithreading for this exercise.

Comment: OpenMP is not MPI. OpenMP creates multiple threads inside the same process. MPI just creates more processes. So if you compare MPI with OpenMP is like you compare MPI with MultiThreading.

Answer (score 0):

It's **easy** to make a multi-threaded application that runs slower than a single threaded application.

You can even use pthread capabilities to make a single threaded application run rather slow. For example, consider a function that consists of a loop, the body of which increments a global counter. You have to protect that increment to make this function usable in a multi-threaded application. For example, sandwich the increment between a mutex lock and unlock. This thread-safe version runs considerably slower than the basic version when there's but one thread. Add another thread and boom! performance degrades massively.

While you should never do this, the above shows that

- There's a bit of overhead involved with threading.
- There's an immense amount of overhead and waste when contention is high. You want the code to do something between unlocks and locks. Making almost everything critical defeats the purpose of multi threading.

I mentioned mutexes because you elided (didn't show) a bunch of code. If you have a lot of locking and unlocking going on in that elided code, that might be part of your problem.

Another way to make a multi-threaded application perform worse than serially is to overwhelm your machine. A rule of thumb is that you shouldn't have more than M active threads using the CPUs, where M is the number of effective CPUs on your machine. Unless you are running your code on a blade server, this M is a smallish number. You are creating a lot of contention if you have many more than M active threads that are trying to use the CPU. Your 4*N is most likely a lot more than this M.

You can't just spawn thread after thread after thread and expect performance to improve. This is a good recipe for degraded performance.  If you have a large number of computations you want to run in parallel using coarse-grained parallelism (e.g., threads), it's best to use a thread pool. A thread pool limits the number of active threads. POSIX threads doesn't provide a thread pool capability. You'll have to roll your own or find one on the internet that suits your needs.

Yet another way you can make a multi-threaded application perform worse than serially is to not join finished threads. You are creating a lot of unjoinable threads with your code. Even if they have finished, you still have a problem because those finished but unjoined threads represent resources that add to contention. And if they're not finished, you are overwhelming your machine.